# Stuck with react native redash library

Tags: typescript, react-native

I get stuck with react-native-redash library when coding [(Instagram Pinch-to-Zoom](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MukiK57qwVY)). I can not use Vector (or vec) and onGestureEvent from react-native-redash such as in this Video. Because there is no implementation for them (vec just have "create function" and does not have "set function")

Does anybody know what problem is? I have used Typescript for my project. And I have read [v1 Users notice](https://wcandillon.gitbook.io/redash/) in redash docs but don't know which circumstance to apply it. Thank in advance.

Library I used in my project:

"react-native-reanimated": "~1.7.0"

"react-native-redash": "^15.6.0"

"react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.6.0"

"react-native": "0.61.4"

Answer (score 3):

I get answer after doing some steps below:

- Add this line "include": ["node_modules/react-native-redash/lib/typescript/v1/index.d.ts"] to tsconfig.
- Import any function / variable you need from [v1 docs](https://wcandillon.github.io/react-native-redash-v1-docs/). For example, you want to add 'onGestureEvent' function: import {onGestureEvent} from  "react-native-redash/lib/module/v1";

But I get some new problems with tsconfig such as alias setup for some paths is alerted with red underline and code suggestion is not working with function/ variable from this "react-native-redash/lib/module/v1".

Answer (score 0):

Use `"react-native-redash": "^14.2.3"` as stated here:
https://github.com/wcandillon/can-it-be-done-in-react-native/blob/master/the-10-min/package.json

and here:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-redash